# How to clean HornetQ messaging journal before/after performing a test?

Tags: java, jms, java-ee-6, jboss7.x, hornetq

There's an **Arquillian** integration test using **JMS HornetQ** with persisted messages. Some test leave the messaging journal filled with unhandled messages that break other tests expecting no data.

Is there a way of telling **JMS** to clean its messaging journal before or after executing a test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not exist in the JMS API itself, but there's a method 'removeMessages(filter)' in the HornetQ QueueControl management object. This method can be found in the JMX Bean for the Queue, but I wouldn't know how to get that in Arquillian.

Luckily, you can invoke management operations via the 'hornetq.management' queue. See http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/management.html. In practice, the following should work:

```
     Queue managementQueue = HornetQJMSClient.createQueue("hornetq.management");
     QueueRequestor requestor = new QueueRequestor(session, managementQueue);
     Message m = session.createMessage();
     JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(m,
                                                "jms.queue.exampleQueue",
                                                "removeMessages","*");
     Message reply = requestor.request(m);
     boolean success = JMSManagementHelper.hasOperationSucceeded(reply);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're restarting the server, you could remove the paging and data folders (while keeping the bindings).

Comment: details of how to do that would be useful

Comment: There are 4 folders: bindings, journal
largemessages, paging,  give a reboot and no historic data needed can we delete the contents of the last 3?